# Could not make proto path relative and No such file or directory

Tags: dart, protocol-buffers, prototype, proto

```
go-dev
 -blog
  -blog-server
  -blogpb
    - blog.proto
 -other 
 -dart
```

i have a directory like that on my project `blogpb` is the directory where i create `.proto` file to `dart` directory, 
when i run this command:

```
 protoc -I=. --dart_out=$DST_DIR $SRC_DIR/blogpb/blog.proto  
 // got : Could not make proto path relative: /blogpb/blog.proto: No such file or directory

 protoc --dart_out=grpc:lib/src/generated -Iprotos greet/greetpb/greet.proto
 // got : protos: warning: directory does not exist.
 //       Could not make proto path relative: greet/greetpb/greet.proto: No such file or directory
```

what is the wrong command above ? and how to create the `generated` into `dart` directory for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could make it work that I must create directory `lib/src/generated` and change the command to

```
protoc --dart_out=grpc:lib/src/generated -Iblogpb blogpb/blog.proto
```

`-Iblogpb` meant what the directory of our *.proto

if you want `myprotos`, you can change `-Iblogpb` to `-Imyprotos` :)

Comment: I don't know how, but it really worked. Changing the gradle version, changing packages versions, adding a package that fixes enum errors did not help, but your solution helped. Thank you very much! Only we moved the generation to `lib/generated`